QEMU - Bridge networking does not work on Debian Bookworm guest on M1 Pro host
I have a Macbook Pro M1 Pro host running a Ubuntu and Debian guests on UTM. The Debian guest is unable to connect to the internet if I use anything but emulated VLAN as the network setting. This is not ideal as I need to ssh into other devices in my network from the Debian guest. This issue does not exist on the Ubuntu guest. Setting the Ubuntu guest to bridged networking works as intended. I can get an IP address and ssh into other devices on the network, and access the internet.
To see if this is a UTM or a Debian issue, I have tried using VMWare Fusion to create a Debian guest and set the networking to bridged. Same result: Ubuntu works and Debian doesn't.
I am running UTM Version 4.4.5 (94) and the Debian image is from an installer on the debian.org page. It is Debian Bookworm. It is important to note that even as I was installing debian, the installer would not be able to connect to any of the debian mirrors (or in fact any website from the console) when bridged networking is enabled. The installer was successfully able to connect when emulated VLAN was chosen.
I am attaching the QEMU log from my last login, with the debian guest configured with bridged, set to automatic and the isolate from host unchecked. I have tried any combination of these options to no avail.
While using the emulated VLAN (sort of) works, it is a not a workaround I like. I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in solving this problem. Thanks.

Does HenkPoley's comment here fix the issue?

@eyoung100 I am not running a usual desktop environment so I would need to make those changes through the terminal. I am not sure how to do that...

Add the output of which resolvconf and cat /etc/resolve.conf | grep name to your question.

> which resolvconf
resolvconf not found
> cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep name
nameserver 192.168.1.1

See Debian: resolvconf and What overwrites /etc/resolv.conf on every boot?.  Make sure it's NOT overwritten after you replace 192.168.1.1 with 1.1.1.1, 8.8.4.4
